# Unable to call class bark()

Tags: python, class

I am new to python and I have written the below code.

I don't understand why I can't call the bark() class from the object
and print it out. I am using eclipse pydev

Please help!!

```
class DOG():
    def __init__(self,mybreed):
        self.breed = mybreed
        def bark(self):
            print("WOOF {}".format(mybreed))

my_dog = DOG(mybreed="Goat")

print(my_dog.breed)
my_dog.breed = 'WOLF'
print(my_dog.breed)

print(my_dog.bark())
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is indents, you have defined `brak` inside `__init__`, change your class definition to this:

```
class DOG():
    def __init__(self, mybreed):
        self.breed = mybreed

    def bark(self):
        print("WOOF {}".format(self.breed))
```

> In most other programming languages, indentation is used only to help make the code look pretty. But in Python, it is required for indicating what block of code a statement belongs to.

Useful link: [Here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)

Thanks to @nixon, also for accessing the instance attributes you should use `self`, look more carefully at `format(self.breed)`.

Comment: You have assigned `mybreed` to the instance attribute `self.breed`, so you have to refer to it as so in `bark()`. This code would raise ean error.

Comment: That's Right, Thanks.